# Creating a simple Javascript Pin code validation

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a pin validation in javascript. I want to ask the user for a pin and they input 1234. If they enter the wrong pin 3 times I want it to say the message "incorrect pin. contact bank". Thanks for any help

```js
function pinCode() {
  const Pin = "1234"; {}
  const name = prompt("Please enter your full name");
  const user_Attempt = prompt("Please enter your PIN number to access your bank account");
  if (user_Attempt = Pin) {
    alert("Welcome" + name);
  } else {
    alert("Incorrect pin. Please contact your bank");
    return;
  }

}
```

Comment: `=` should be `==` in the `if` statement

Comment: The `=` not being `==` will cause it to assign the value of `Pin` to `user_Attempt` instead of comparing their value

Answer (score 0):

```js
const pin = "1234";

let attemptsLeft = 3


const name = prompt("Please enter your full name");
for (attemptsLeft; attemptsLeft >= 0; attemptsLeft--) {
  if (attemptsLeft === 0) {
    alert("Incorrect pin. Please contact your bank");
    break;
  }
  const userAttempt = prompt(`Please enter your PIN number to access your bank account. You have ${attemptsLeft} left.`);
  if (userAttempt === pin) {
    alert("Welcome " + name);
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `while` loop to keep looping until either the `attempts` run out or `pinCorrect` is `true`.

```js
const correctPin = '1234';
const maxAttempts = 3;
let attempts = 0;
let pinCorrect = false;

while (attempts < maxAttempts && !pinCorrect) {
  const pinInput = prompt(`Please enter your PIN number to access your bank account. ${maxAttempts - attempts} attempts left.`);
  pinCorrect = pinInput === correctPin;
  attempts++;
}

if (!pinCorrect) {
  alert('Incorrect pin. Please contact your bank');
} else {
  alert('Pin accepted');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use recursion for this

```
var incorrectCount = 0;

function pinCode() {
    if (incorrectCount != 3) {
        // prompts here
        if (user_Attempt === Pin) {
            // do stuff
         } else {
           incorrectCount += 1;
           pinCode();
        }
    } else {
        // code for too many incorrect tries
    }
}
```